# Detecting noise in speech transcription from only text

Tags: nlp, speech-to-text

Is there a way method to detect words that were poorly transcribed in a text transcription? The situation is as follows, I want to do some NLP tasks on the transcription of a phone call, but the phone call transcription is noisy, words like airpod or airport are switched. I have no access to the transcription service or model only the text. I was hoping for a way to detect these sorts of words and use a LM to replace them with a word that makes more sense based on the context.

Any research, papers or blogs would be much appreciated, I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Even a human proficient in the language being used would have some difficulty with this task. You first have to identify words that are incorrectly recognized. Then you have to guess what was the word actually intended by the speaker. Then there's the problem that in natural speech, it's probably not uncommon that people speak the "wrong" word, but human listeners fill in the meaning based on context, perhaps without even being aware of it.  Good luck with your project to second guess what people meant to say.

Comment: Ok, that may be slightly snarky. A useful tool for parts of this would be a dictionary of words commonly confused (including all literal homophones). The you'd need a way to evaluate the permutations of the text to determine the best substitutions. The process is akin to grammar checking and correction. It would be easy to end up with more noise than the original.

Comment: I recently had to transcript dialogues from a recording. I did it all by hand. I guarantee that not a single person in those recordings used correct grammar. Everyone was repeating words as they were searching for the words to express what they wanted to say. It was borderline stuttering. In many sentences, the speaker repeats the same word up to five times before moving on to the rest of the sentence. And no one noticed this disregard for grammar when the dialogue happened - only when I had to transcript the recording.